# updating and deleting record through model binding in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I post model object from view in which  parent and child list exist and also I am taking one another object which I am fetch from database.So I am comparing objects like

```
public bool ChildRecords(CheckListTemplate questList)
        {
            int templateId = questList.Id;
            if (templateId > 0 && questList.Questions.Count() > 0)
            {
                var template =DBContext.CheckListTemplates.Include(p => p.Questions).SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == templateId);
                template.Name = questList.Name;
                List<CheckListQuestion> delQuestions = new List<CheckListQuestion>();
                foreach(CheckListQuestion q in template.Questions)
                {
                    var question = questList.Questions.Where(x => x.Id == q.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (question == null)
                    {
                                               delQuestions.Add(q);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        q.Question = question.Question;
                        q.Clause = question.Clause;
                    }
                }
                if(delQuestions.Count()>0)
                {
                    foreach(CheckListQuestion qst in  delQuestions)
                    {
                        var itemToRemove = template.Questions.Single(r => r.Id == qst.Id);
                        template.Questions.Remove(qst);
                    }
                }                
DBContext.Entry(template).State = EntityState.Modified;
                DBContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I am updating and deleting records.If i update the record function work fine but when i delete the record and post the view then DBContext.Entry(template).State = EntityState.Modified;
 is giving error.How can I delete record.What I am missing inside the code.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you could share the error with us. But looking at your code, probably the error you are facing is because you are trying to delete some record inside a loop and that doesn't works.

You can simplify your code by storing in memory only the ids of the records you want to delete. Example:

```
    public bool ChildRecords(CheckListTemplate questList)
    {
        int templateId = questList.Id;
        if (templateId > 0 && questList.Questions.Count() > 0)
        {
            var template = DBContext.CheckListTemplates.Include(p => p.Questions).SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == templateId);
            template.Name = questList.Name;
            List<int> delQuestions = new List<int>();
            foreach(CheckListQuestion q in template.Questions)
            {
                var question = questList.Questions.Where(x => x.Id == q.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (question == null)
                   delQuestions.Add(q.Id);
                else
                {
                    q.Question = question.Question;
                    q.Clause = question.Clause;
                }
            }

            if(delQuestions.Count()>0)
               DBContext.CheckListTemplates.RemoveRange(DBContext.CheckListTemplates.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)));

            DBContext.Entry(template).State = EntityState.Modified;
            DBContext.SaveChanges();
         }
     }
```

Comment: I am not deleting the record in loop.I am just adding in object list and delete later when loop finished.I want operation through one object list through entity state modified.

Comment: This you cannot do. That's what I'm talking about....


                         foreach(CheckListQuestion qst in  delQuestions)
                         {
                             var itemToRemove = template.Questions.Single(r => r.Id == qst.Id);
                            template.Questions.Remove(qst);
                         }

If you really need to do this for some reason use for instead of foreach.